# Moodle REST API to get all the course list and users enrolled for that particular courses

Tags: moodle

There is any Moodle REST API available to get all the course name list and all the users enrolled for that particular courses.

Someone suggest the answer using SQl query. But I need any Moodle API available for that.

API is available for get all the users enrolled for single course by passing courseId in core_enrolled_get_enrolled_users . But I have to display all the courses and number of users enrolled for that course in  charts . Please find below the sample charts :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may first get courses through `core_course_get_courses` and then iterate resulting array and apply `core_enrolled_get_enrolled_users` to each course id.

Comment: I have found your response useful however, the webservice needs to be updated to `core_enrol_get_enrolled_users`. The full list can be found here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions